# Can I use a variable as parameter to AWK's {print}?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh

I have this bash statement for printing a specific cell from a .csv file.

```
set `cat $filename | awk -v FS=',' '{print $2}' | head -5 | tail -n 1`
```

The `'{print $2}'` part determines the column and the `head -5` part determines the row.

Can I substitute a `$counter` variable in place of `$2`  (e.g., `'{print $counter}'`)?

Comment: Yes. Also note that your pipe via `cat` is a bit useless, because `awk` takes a filename as input anyhow.

Comment: `head -5` ... needs to be replaced with `head -n 5`

Comment: If you don't set `counter`, it will print `$0` (because `counter` will be treated as 0).  If you set `counter` to a column number, `print $counter` will print the column number indicated by the current value of `counter` at the time the `print` is executed.  So, you can print column N of the input with `N=5; awk -v N="$N" '{print $N}'` (for N=5 in this example).

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes" -- and there are a couple ways to do what you want. The proper way is to declare an **awk** variable using `-v`:

```
awk -F',' -v c=$counter 'NR==6 { print $c; exit }' "$filename"
```

(You will forgive me for moving some things around to do everything in **awk**, for passing `"$filename"` to **awk** safely, and for getting rid of `set` and back ticks -- that were doing nothing for the cause.)

Another way to do this is a bit of a "hackish" way -- leveraging shell quoting rules. This method requires some escaping to ensure that the first `$` character (that references the intended *field* in **awk**) is not interpreted by the shell... The following works in **bash** (and POSIX **sh**):

```
awk -F',' "NR==6 { print \$$counter; exit }" "$filename"
```

Comment: Isn't it enouhg: `NR==6 { print $c ; exit; } ` ?

Comment: Thank you for reducing the redundancy of my code. I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and all pipes could be removed. Variables are passed to `awk` with `-v var=value`.

Give a try to this tested version. Provide a value to the ̀`col` and `row` variables:

```
set $(awk -F "," -v col=2 -v row=5 'NR==row {print $col; exit}' "${filename}")
```

`$(command)` is prefered to `command`, this later is deprecated.

`NR` is the current line number.

`"${filename}"` is expanded by the shell to its value: the double quotes will help if the filename contains some special chars.

Comment: answer updated with a tested version, copy+pasted from shell terminal.